# how to trigger react, to rerender the UI, with socket?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, redux

this is my working code:

```
import socket from 'components/io/socket';
import store from 'components/store';
// globally available socket connection
class ChatBox extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
     socket.on("message", this.props.addChat.bind(this));
     // this.props.addChat is reduxer actions.
  }
}
```

however, I'm worried that such code, would likely introduce a memory leak since the older ChatBox component would still be refered by the socket.

I tried to change it into:

```
import socket from 'components/io/socket';
import store from 'components/store';
socket.on("message", store.dispatch(addChat({...}))

class ChatBox extends React.Component {
  render(){ ... }
}
```

however the second code doesnt trigger the html to be rerendered, even though when I use the breakpoint, and calls, `store.getState()` the result change after the socket received message.

Answer (score 1):

You can override [componentWillUnmmount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) to unsubscribe the listener and thus making the socket release the reference to the ChatBox you are worried about.

However, since each call to `bind` creates a brand new instance, you won't have the listener reference at `componentWillUnmmount`. To solve this, bind the method in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.addChat = this.props.addChat.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  socket.on("message", this.addChat);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  socket.off("message", this.addChat); // or whatever it is called
}
```

Anyway, it seems strange to me to have an extraneous method (passed from outside by `props`) bound to the component. Usually you subscribe a method of the component itself, so you can be sure about what is happening - specially because the method can freely change any properties of the instance, like state or event the addChat binding. So, you might want review this. Maybe convert to a high order component?